# Better way to get approximate ground track for a satellite using Skyfield?

Tags: python, skyfield, coordinates

I wanted to make a quick ground-track plot, so I used the Python package [Skyfield](http://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/) to propagate a TLE and return Earth-Centered Inertial coordinates. Then I created a `Topos()` object fixed to the Earth's surface at lat/lon = 0, 0 and used it to generate the rotation of the earth in order to "unwind" the ISS position on the surface.

**side note:** This is not a good way to do this, but it gives results good enough to make a small map for an illustration. Problems include assuming the earth's axis is still in the z direction, and of course treating the earth's surface as spherical.

Is there a better way to do this within Skyfield without using a method that starts with an underscore - in other words using methods intended to be completely public for the user? Also, is there a way to get the Earth centered, Earth fixed (i.e. rotating Earth) coordinates directly in Skyfield without unwinding like this?

**EDIT:** I've adjusted the script since it's been over a year and Skyfield v 1.0 has been released.

```
ISS_TLE = """1 25544U 98067A   16341.96974289  .00003303  00000-0  57769-4 0  9996
2 25544  51.6456 276.4739 0005937 300.1004 104.8148 15.53811586 31866"""
L1, L2 = ISS_TLE.splitlines()

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skyfield.api import Loader, EarthSatellite, Topos

degs     = 180./np.pi

r_earth  = 6371.  # for ROUGH approx. ground track, just use a spherical Earth

load    = Loader('~/Documents/YourNameHere/SkyData')
data    = load('de421.bsp')
earth   = data['earth']
topoZZ  = Topos(latitude_degrees=0.0, longitude_degrees=0.0)

location = earth + topoZZ

ISS      = earth + EarthSatellite(L1, L2)

ts       = load.timescale()

minutes  = np.arange(0, 140, 0.5)
time     = ts.utc(2016, 12, 7, 12, minutes)

Epos     = earth.at(time).position.km
ZZpos    = topoZZ.at(time).position.km    ## Position of (0.0N, 0.0E) to get rotation
ISSpos   = ISS.at(time).position.km - Epos

theta_ZZ = np.arctan2(ZZpos[1], ZZpos[0])   # calculate Earth's rotaion

sth, cth         = np.sin(-theta_ZZ), np.cos(-theta_ZZ) # unwind
xISS, yISS, zISS = ISSpos
xISSnew, yISSnew = xISS*cth - yISS*sth, xISS*sth + yISS*cth # rotate ISS data to match Earth
ISSnew           = np.vstack((xISSnew, yISSnew, zISS))

x, y, z = ISSnew
r       = np.sqrt((ISSpos**2).sum(axis=0))
rxy     = np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)
ISSlat, ISSlon   = np.arctan2(z, rxy), np.arctan2(y, x)

plt.figure()
plt.plot(degs*ISSlon, degs*ISSlat, 'ok')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This has been asked here also: https://github.com/skyfielders/python-skyfield/issues/121

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know this is an old question but for funsies, here's a quick script.

This question was asked when the [`.subpoint()`](https://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/api-position.html#skyfield.positionlib.Geocentric.subpoint) feature wasn't supported in Skyfield to grab the long/lat for a satellite orbit projected onto the Earth.

Here's a quick script that shows how to use Skyfield's built in functions with plotting using cartopy to build the map and projections.

```
from skyfield.api import load, EarthSatellite
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

ts = load.timescale(builtin=True)


TLE = """ISS (ZARYA)             
1 25544U 98067A   19203.81086311  .00000606  00000-0  18099-4 0  9996
2 25544  51.6423 184.5274 0006740 168.1171 264.4057 15.50995519180787"""

name, L1, L2 = TLE.splitlines()

sat = EarthSatellite(L1, L2)

minutes = np.arange(0, 200, 0.1) # about two orbits
times   = ts.utc(2019, 7, 23, 0, minutes)

geocentric = sat.at(times)
subsat = geocentric.subpoint()

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())

ax.stock_img()

plt.scatter(subsat.longitude.degrees, subsat.latitude.degrees, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),
            color='red')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Excellent! For additional funsies how about a way to construct a terrestrial subpoint for another object? Comments below [this question](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/34084/7982) as well in [this chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101497/discussion-between-rasika-and-uhoh) suggest that the OP would eventually like to plot a trail of the sub-planet points across the Earth's surface. I can think of two ways; 1) use `reverse_terra()` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54990129/3904031) (cont.)

Comment: ...or 2)  construct a [Geocentric](https://rhodesmill.org/skyfield/api-position.html#skyfield.positionlib.Geocentric) object in Skyfield based on the planet's positions and then apply `.subpoint()` to it. Unfortunately the text of that question hasn't been updated to reflect the OP's intent yet. (note: the linked question is in [Astronomy SE](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/) not here in Space SE], it's common to confuse the two)

Comment: fyi now that you are above 50 reputation points you can leave comments on any posts you like!

Comment: I've found that the line "ax.stock_img() results in the following python error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cartopy/data/raster/natural_earth/50-natural-earth-1-downsampled.png'  - it seems the folder structure has changed and that image moved. Where else is the same file available?